# C# - higher or lower statement in a switch function

Tags: c#

Only `if(artikelen > 50)` works. I think I know why, but I don't know how to resolve the problem.

switch function, but I don't know how to use "< or >" in that function.

C#:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    double bruto = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    double artikelen = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    double loon;
    if (artikelen < 10) {
        double twee = bruto + (bruto / 100 * 2);
        loon = twee;
        textBox3.Text = loon.ToString();
    }
    if (artikelen >= 10 && bruto < 50) {
        double vijf = bruto + (bruto / 100 * 5);
        loon = vijf;
        textBox3.Text = loon.ToString();
    }
    if (artikelen > 50) {
        double tien = bruto + (bruto / 100 * 10);
        loon = tien;
        textBox3.Text = loon.ToString();
    }
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
}
```

Comment: "Only "if(artikelen > 50)" works, I think I know why" Can you enlighten us? I don´t even know what "works" mean. What is your specific problem? What does your debugger do when you step through the code? What should your program do and what do you get instead? What is your input-data? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If `artikelen` is greater 50 it certainly is also greater 10, isn´t it? Just a sidenote.

Comment: Are those doubles monetary amounts?

Comment: did you mean `if (artikelen >= 10 && artikelen < 50)` for your second condition?

Comment: "I don´t even know what "works" mean." means , we cannot know what you understand by "does not work". Is there an error? Do you get unexpected results? Compile time errors? Runtime Errors? ... For which cases do errors happen and so on.

Comment: BTW _"Even my teacher doesn't know"_ - some teachers purposely "don't know" because they want you to find out instead of being fed the solution.

Comment: Ah, ok. Anyways my teacher actually didn't knew, she had to search it up

Comment: If only if(artikelen > 50) is being hit then it means all artikelen are greater than 50....

Answer (score 0):

You can use less than or greater than in a `switch` statement with C# 7:

```
switch (value)
{
    case var _ when value < 10:
        // something
        break;
    case var _ when (value >= 10 && value < 50):
        // something
        break;
    case var _ when value > 50:
        // something
        break;
    default:
        // something
        break;
}
```

For multiple inputs, look at [tuple patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#tuple-patterns) in C# 8.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a lot of duplicate code.

I'd split that into:

```
decimal GetFactor( decimal artikelen )
{   // order is important!
    if( artikelen >= 50 ) return 10m;
    if( artikelen >= 10 ) return 5m;
    return 2m;
}
```

To get the factor. Then do the math:

```
decimal GetLoon( decimal bruto, decimal factor ) // With factor from above result
{
    return bruto + (bruto / 100m * factor);
}
```

Resulting in

```
textBox3.Text = GetLoon( bruto, GetFactor( artikelen) ).ToString();
```

Some additional points:

- I assume these are monetary amounts. => Use `decimal`, not floating point!
- Always validate user input. What if a value cannot be parsed? What if artikelen < 0 ?